# Binary search tree with python generators

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I got the problem to find the height from a partially completed code sample of BST implementation as below.

```
class BST:

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None):
            self.key = key
            self.left = left
            self.right = right

        def __iter__(self):     
            if self.left:
                yield from self.left
            yield self.key
            if self.right:
                yield from self.right

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def __iter__(self):         
        if self.root:
            yield from self.root

    def insert(self, key):
        self.root = self._insert(self.root, key)

    def _insert(self, r, key):
        if r is None:
            return self.Node(key)
        elif key < r.key:
            r.left = self._insert(r.left, key)
        elif key > r.key:
            r.right = self._insert(r.right, key)
        else:
            pass  
        return r

    def print(self):
        self._print(self.root)

    def _print(self, r):
        if r:
            self._print(r.left)
            print(r.key, end=' ')
            self._print(r.right)

    def contains(self, k):
        n = self.root
        while n and n.key != k:
            if k < n.key:
                n = n.left
            else:
                n = n.right
        return n is not None

    def size(self):
        return self._size(self.root)

    def _size(self, r):
        if r is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + self._size(r.left) + self._size(r.right)
```

I tried to implement "def height(self):  " method, referencing[Binary search tree](https://thatmattbone.com/binary-tree-traversal-in-python-with-generators.html)

I tried left and right nodes as below

```
 for node in self.root.__iter__():
             print(node)
```

But, I was unable to understand how to work with generators and implement this height method.Hope your support. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use generators?  And if so, are you required to use the particular generators that are already defined in the classes provided?

Comment: I ask because the defined generators serve as a fairly clean way to implement an in-order traversal of the tree, but they don't provide any good way to use such a traversal to determine the tree height.

Comment: It *is* possible to write a generator-based solution that is not overly contrived, but you would need to define an additional generator for the purpose.

Comment: @JohnBollinger seems he has not better undestand about generators. he is seeking help to understand and implement height function too.

Comment: Can you add code for a failing test case?

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom tried something like this:
    def height(self):                             # Compulsory
        if self.root is None:
            return 0
        else:
            lHeight=height(self.left)
            rHeight=height(self.right)
            if (lHeight > rHeight):
                return lHeight+1
            else:
                return rHeight+1
but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you edit that into the question, so it has code, inputs, and expected output?